# PHP: Using API key in CURL GET Call

Tags: php, json, api, rest, curl

I have seen the post for using api key for authenticating post calls in curl. I have a GET call that requires apikey for authorization i.e the request must have an authorization header cantaining the apiKey. I have obtained the api key and try to use it for a GET call :

```
<?php

$service_url = 'http://localhost/finals/task_manager/v1/tasks/Authorization:'.$apiKey;
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
if ($curl_response === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
}

curl_close($curl);
$decoded1 = json_decode($curl_response,true);
if (isset($decoded1->response->status) && $decoded1->response->status == 'ERROR') {
    die('error occured: ' . $decoded1->response->errormessage);
}
echo 'response ok!';
var_export($decoded1->response);
?>
```

I am getting error in json response:

```
{"error":true,"message":"Api key is misssing"}
```

I have tried a few other ways like passing a header array but i keep getting the error.
How to correctly get the curl_response ? How should I pass the Authorization header which uses the api key ?

The api for the get call I am making is (created using Slim Library) :

```
index.php
/**
 * Listing all tasks of particual user
 * method GET
 * url /tasks          
 */
$app->get('/tasks', 'authenticate', function() {
            global $user_id;
            $response = array();
            $db = new DbHandler();

            // fetching all user tasks
            $result = $db->getAllUserTasks($user_id);

            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["tasks"] = array();

            // looping through result and preparing tasks array
            while ($task = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $tmp = array();
                $tmp["id"] = $task["id"];
                $tmp["task"] = $task["task"];
                $tmp["status"] = $task["status"];
                $tmp["createdAt"] = $task["created_at"];
                array_push($response["tasks"], $tmp);
            }

            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        });
```

The authenticate function is :

```
in the same index.php file
/**
 * Adding Middle Layer to authenticate every request
 * Checking if the request has valid api key in the 'Authorization' header
 */
function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
    // Getting request headers
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    $response = array();
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

    // Verifying Authorization Header
    if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
        $db = new DbHandler();

        // get the api key
        $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];
        // validating api key
        if (!$db->isValidApiKey($api_key)) {
            // api key is not present in users table
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Access Denied. Invalid Api key";
            echoRespnse(401, $response);
            $app->stop();
        } else {
            global $user_id;
            // get user primary key id
            $user = $db->getUserId($api_key);
            if ($user != NULL)
                $user_id = $user["id"];
        }
    } else {
        // api key is missing in header
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Api key is misssing";
        echoRespnse(400, $response);
        $app->stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Without knowing the exact API or your calls, it's going to be hard to tell really...
Some APIs require specific methods to be sent as well, in addition to headers.

Comment: @trueicecold I put the api.please take a look.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ok so it should be pretty straightforward... Could you try and add:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Authorization: ' . $apiKey
));
```

to your curl? After that, do a print_r($headers) in your authenticate() function to see if you receive it ok.

Comment: Thanks it works, I had tried something similar but was including too many things. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

Access web service using custom Authorization key.

PHP Client,client.php

```
$name = 'Book name';
//Server url
$url = "http://localhost/php-rest/book/$name";
$apiKey = '32Xhsdf7asd5'; // should match with Server key
$headers = array(
     'Authorization: '.$apiKey
);
// Send request to Server
$ch = curl_init($url);
// To save response in a variable from server, set headers;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// Get response
$response = curl_exec($ch);
// Decode
$result = json_decode($response);
```

PHP Server, index.php

```
header("Content-Type:application/json");
$seceretKey = '32Xhsdf7asd';
$headers = apache_request_headers();
    if(isset($headers['Authorization'])){
        $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];
        if($api_key != $seceretKey) 
        {
            //403,'Authorization faild'; your logic
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to overcome this problem when passing Api key from Advance rest client use Authorization  rather than authorization in header parameter. then it will work.